# Deployment automation of RPGLE with Gradle on IBM i

Tags: gradle, jenkins, continuous-integration, ibm-midrange, rpgle

Does anyone have an expertise on building IBM i software: rpgle, sqlrpgle, clle programs, srvpgms with gradle?

The idea for now is:

- all source code stored in git repo
- jenkins ci, integrated with git, pulls software update
- there is a json file in commit also, where stored a full description of release (project info, dependencies, all objects description with build instructions), just like pom.xml in maven
- on that place jenkins should run gradle task that should build all programs from source code in jenkins working directory, based on instructions in json file. But the problem is - for IBM i compilation available only on server and there is no plugins available for that.

The gradle project should be something like this:

- transfer source code on server
- execute remote compilation of each object with instructions from json
- deploy binaries in specified libraries
- execute commands - create dataara, change it, run sql scripts and others

So the questions are:

1. Is that scheme correct?
2. Are gradle project phases correct?
3. How can I implement that in gradle?

Comment: This is a nice question, worth asking. I doubt there is anyone who uses Gradle for building software on the i. I doubt there is more than a handful of people in the i community that have even heard of Gradle. (I had not heard of it until reading this question, even though I do try to keep up with the news in the mainstream computing world, not just on the i.) But in principle it should be possible to implement your scheme.

Comment: I also want to be clear that I like this question even though it doesn't quite meet the usual Stack Overflow guidelines. This question is a bit too broad, with too many subquestions. If it had been targeting Linux instead of IBM i, I actually would have considered voting to close. But I think it's important that software such as Gradle gets exposure in the IBM i community (which is notoriously unaware of "outside" technologies).

Answer (score 3):

I know I am a little late but for anyone reading it later on here are my 2 cents:

I have done the Jenkins, Git and compile part of the question. Though I have used a simple shell script instead of gradle but that could be adjusted.

Here are my documented steps: http://wiki.rpgnextgen.com/doku.php?id=ibm_i_and_continuous_integration

And I used the following repo for testing: https://bitbucket.org/m1hael/linkedlist